# How to execute different commands from cmd in same cmd process?

Tags: delphi

I would like to start one `cmd` process and keep feeding it some different commands. I would like to get every text `cmd` output as soon as text is out. So far I have this:

```
function GetDosOutput(const ACommandLine: string;
  AWorkDir: string = 'C:\'): string;
var
  _SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  _SI: TStartupInfo;
  _PI: TProcessInformation;
  _StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  _WasOK: boolean;
  _Buffer: array [0 .. 255] of AnsiChar;
  _BytesRead: Cardinal;
  _Handle: boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  _SA.nLength := SizeOf(_SA);
  _SA.bInheritHandle := True;
  _SA.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  CreatePipe(_StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @_SA, 0);
  try
    FillChar(_SI, SizeOf(_SI), 0);
    _SI.cb := SizeOf(_SI);
    _SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    _SI.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
    _SI.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    _SI.hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
    _SI.hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    _Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + ACommandLine), nil, nil,
      True, 0, nil, PChar(AWorkDir), _SI, _PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if _Handle then
      try
        repeat
          _WasOK := ReadFile(_StdOutPipeRead, _Buffer, 255, _BytesRead, nil);
          if _BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            _Buffer[_BytesRead] := #0;
            Result := Result + string(_Buffer);
            Application.ProcessMessages;
          end;
        until not _WasOK or (_BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(_PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(_PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(_PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(_StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;
```

How do I keep same `cmd.exe` process and give it different commands, e.g.
1) ping stackoverflow.com, see its content as soon as one line is printed
2) `ipconfig /all` ?

Comment: You need to use `cmd.exe /K` instead of `cmd.exe /C`.  `/C` executes 1 command and then terminates the process.  `/K` executes 1 command and then keeps the process running. Also, responses are not delimited in any way, so you won't know exactly when a response finishes.  You will need a timeout on `ReadFile()`, or you can use `PeekNamedPipe()` to detect data before then using `ReadFile()` to read it.

Comment: But why are you using `cmd.exe` at all? There are plenty of Win32 API functions available for the type of operations you mentioned, eg: `ping` -> [`IcmpSendEcho()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho), `ipconfig` -> [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses), etc.

Comment: Remy, because WinAPI tries to fool me. I spent few hours until I found out that VPN network was renamed, but CoNetworkListManager+GetNetworkConnections still returns old name even after PC reboot. By the way, how do I feed new command to `cmd.exe /K`?

Comment: Then why use delphi at all? I bet it would be far easier to make a powershell script to do what you want...

Comment: How about creating a .BAT file with the commands in, and then executing this file via cmd.exe /C RUN.BAT ?

Comment: @EdijsKolesnikovičs I seriously doubt that. `ipconfig` uses the APIs internally, so it should be the same information. What does `GetAdaptersAddresses()` report vs `CoNetworkListManager`? As for `cmd.exe`, once you have the process running, you simply `WriteFile()` to the `stdin` pipe, and then read from the `stdout`/`stderr` pipe